# how to include locate on `root :to`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, root

```
root :to => 'StaticPages#index'
```

returns `http://localhost:3000/`

However, I would like to always show the full path in the root, as I am using the path for layout purposes. I need my root to always be:

```
http://localhost:3000/en/home
```

Does anyone know how to achieve it?

**EDIT** - The reason: I am highlighting the current page.

```
link:
<%=  link_to (t 'nav.home'), home_path, id: current_p(home_path) %>

helper:
def current_p(path)
  "current" if current_page?(path)
end
```

It works fine when navigating between pages. However, it will never highlight the home page, as there is no path.
Any idea?

Comment: It is not possible to use root to return something else than '/', which is the root path. This is why it is called root. You can always redirect from root to another url which suits you. If I may ask, why do you need the *path* for *layout* purposes? Does not sound like a good idea to me.

Comment: @BeatRichartz. I have explained the reason. Thanks

Comment: As an alternative, you might try [active_link_to](https://github.com/twg/active_link_to) which does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, I would rewrite the `current_p` helper and redirect to the localized pages directly rather than trying to hack something together with your root, because root per definition always is referring to the root path `/`.

```
def current_p(path)
  paths_to_match = path =~ /\/\w{2}\/home$/ ? ['/', home_path] : [path]
  current = nil  

  paths_to_match.each do |path_to_match|
    current = 'current' if current_page?(path_to_match)
  end

  current
end
```

This will mark both `/(some locale)/home` and `/` as current.

Like this, you maintain full control of your implementation.

Comment: didn't work... the first access to the page (`http://localhost:3000/`) the home page link don't get the `id="current"`... no id at all.

Comment: @gabrielhilal Sorry, I was a bit unsure about how to rewrite the helper. The edited version should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Beat Richartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670034/beat-richartz) for pointing me the right direction. The code provided by him solved the problem, however I will register here the solution I have implemented.

```
def current_p(path)
  if path == home_path
    'current' if current_page?(path) || current_page?('/')
  else
    'current' if current_page?(path)
  end
end
```